# How to map "Go To Implementation" using VsCode Vim?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodevim

I want to map something like **gi** to open a Typescript interface implementation for example. In VsCode the shortcut is Ctrl + F12 and I tried to add a map like this `inoremap gi <C-F12>` in .vimrc file but that does not work.

I also tried to do that in my *settings.json* but still no results.

```
"vim.insertModeKeyBindings": [
   {
      "before": ["g", "I"],
      "after": ["<C-F12>"]
   }
]
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve that by mapping a shortcut to a VSCode command, not a set of keys. If you look at VSCode shortcuts, you can see that the Go To Definition action is related to a command so you can take that command and map to a vim shortcut in your *settings.json* file.

In the example I will map `gI` to `editor.action.goToImplementation` which is the related command.

```
  "vim.insertModeKeyBindings": [
    {
      "before": ["g", "I"],
      "commands": ["editor.action.goToImplementation"]
    }
  ],

  "vim.normalModeKeyBindings": [
    {
      "before": ["g", "I"],
      "commands": ["editor.action.goToImplementation"]
    }
  ]
```

Comment: It works well but why don't just use `i` instead of upper case `I`? it's more convenient.

Comment: I like to use capital letters as secondary keys for vim commands, but it's up to you :)